# Android. Binding service from test case successful but service not listed in getRunningServices() result

Tags: java, android

I'm writing unit tests for my Android service. I can bind service from test case and invoke remote methods. But the check if service is running fails.

Check method:

```
    private boolean isServiceRunning() {
    final ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) this
            .getSystemContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final List<RunningServiceInfo> services = activityManager
            .getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    boolean serviceFound = false;
    for (RunningServiceInfo runningServiceInfo : services) {
        if (runningServiceInfo.service.getClassName().equals(
                MyService.class.getName())) {
            serviceFound = true;
        }
    }
    return serviceFound;
}
```

And test:

```
    public void testInvokeRemoteMethod() {
        Manager manager = null;
        IBinder binder = bindService(new Intent("com.example.myservice.Manager"));

        manager = Manager.Stub.asInterface(binder);

        int ret = 0;
        try {
            ret = manager.testMethod();
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        assertTrue(ret == -55);
        assertTrue(isServiceRunning());
    }
```

Test fails on second assert.

When I starting service "manually" I have no errors.

```
getSystemContext().startService(new Intent("com.example.myservice.Manager"));
assertTrue(isServiceRunning());
```

Documentation on ServiceTestCase.bindService() said that: "The flag is assumed to be BIND_AUTO_CREATE". Is the service exist only when thread of execution is inside one of service's methods?

Comment: This is because your service is bound but not started, read about  bound services here http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

Comment: So the service can be in "bound but not running" or "created but not running" state? It's not clearly documented. Service lifecycle diagram from developer.android starts with "onStartCommand() and onBind() are called".

Comment: if you mean running == started, then yes: bound and started are two independent states, see also http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html esp Figure 2

Comment: Thank you, I don't understand how I missed it.